# How to merge Collectors.counting() to existing HashMap

Tags: hashmap, collectors

my current goal is to merge counted value(Collectors.counting()) to existing HashMap,
see the structure as below:

[image: ```]

this data was from tons of columns with same data,
so this way was kind of best solution to count many of same values.

But if possible, I want to put those values (Long) in HashMap before inserting into database.

Is here any great solution, please help.
(Or if this structure is very bad; Thanks for your advice in advance :)).

Thanks!

---

original data was List<Map<String, Object>>,
and result data came out with Map<Object, Long>.

```
Map<Object, Long> result = errData.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d, Collectors.counting()));
```

---

Desired output should be:

```
result:
  "data" -> 0.0
  "execPlanId" -> "QPLN-20220412-001"
  "columnId" -> "DSCHDRUG"
  "tableName" -> "ODS_APIPDLST" 
  "execId" -> 156
  "errCount" -> 341 (currently on "value" from result HashMap)
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Do you have a `Map<Map, Long>`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguous question - i've just added how the types came with.

Comment: What is your goal? What do you mean by *merge counted value*?

Comment: So the value above from variable "result" is  the number how many duplicate values exist. this value should be merged into the key(the HashMap with column & values) if possible

Comment: Do you want to add the values (341,1382 in the image) to the corresponding hashmap (key) as a new key?

Comment: due to lack of my explanation: this result should point out how many invalid value came out after data examination. so the result will be inserted into an existing table what kind(s) of, and how many kind(s) of data was invalid.

Comment: Can you show the desired output for the first map in the image?

Comment: @user7 yes, and those key HashMap should be sent to query for inserting (result) data

Comment: just added the output you have asked. "errCount" is the key I want to merge("value" from HashMap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the type of the `result` as `Map<Map<String, Object>, Long>`.

Then, you can iterate/stream this map and add a new field as desired.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> resWithErrCount = result.entrySet().stream()
        .map(entry -> {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(entry.getKey());
            map.put("errCount", entry.getValue());
            return map;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: This creates a new HashMap with the added `errCount` field and all maps are collected into a list.

Comment: An error occurs like 'java: cannot infer type arguments for java.util.HashMap<>'.  It was not solved with announcing two types String, Object. Could you help me a little bit more? ;-(

Comment: This compiles fine for me. Check this out - https://ideone.com/BmDGoH (populated `result` with some random data)

Comment: Thank you for your consideration! I have checked your solution works great. Maybe I have a problem with multiple lambdas with (hash)maps.. I'll figure out what happened. Anyway thank you again for having time to help solving this issue!